# Angles of a rhombus given side and height

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am a geometry teacher trying to solve a problem.  Our textbook only gives us the answer and I am the only HS math teacher at the school.  One of my students figured it out, but I cannot understand his solution and I think he assumed something he cannot assume.  The question is:

Find the measure of the obtuse angle of a rhombus given that it has side lengths of 2in and a height of 1in.

My student assumed that the height is also equal to a diagonal, but from my knowledge you cannot do that.

Comment: Your student's assumption is wrong, as the diagonals are approximately $1.0352$ and $3.8637$. Once the angles are found (diagonals are not necessary), we can use the Law of Sines to find the lengths of the diagonals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but it is $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{h}{a}$$ and the other angle is $$180^{\circ}-\alpha$$ whre $a$ is the side length of the given rhombus and $h$ the hight.
so $$\alpha=\frac{\pi}{6}$$ and the searched angle is $$\frac{5\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Here $\alpha$ is the acute angle.   In your case, $\sin(\alpha) = 1/2$, so what do you conclude?